# is it possible to shorten the parameters of a method?

Tags: java, swing, methods

Is it possible to shorten the parameters of a method in java.

e.g.

```
public void testing(String A, String B, String C, JButton A, JButton B, JButton C){
}
```

Since I have 3 String variables and 3 buttons, would it be possible to make this shorten in any way. I have tried `String A,B,C JButton A,B,C` but it is not working.

Comment: No.....................

Comment: You could create a class to encapsulate your parameters, but if it is just for this purpose, I wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could pass arrays or lists, one type of `String` and one of `JButton`.

```
public void testing(String[] strArray, JButton[] btnArray) {

}
```

Comment: Put Strings A,B,C into an array before passing it to the function. Same goes for JButton.

Comment: Very well, actually. If you already are expecting 3 Strings for example, `str 1 = strArray[0]; str 2 = strArray[1]; str 3 = strArray[2]` would work the same as your original implementation.

Comment: Although you could do this, it's really not descriptive code, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: How would you use this? like this... public void testing(String strArray[A, B, C], JButton btnArray[A, B, C])

Comment: No - Like this: public void testing(String[] strArray, JButton[] btnArray)

Comment: What is not always the case?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis passing arrays into functions can be viable. What if String A,B,C were all names? String[] nameArray is plenty descriptive...

Comment: `String firstName, String middleName, String lastName` is more descriptive than `String[] namesArray` with use of `namesArray[0]`, `namesArray[1]`, `namesArray[2]`. In that case, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes, but with all first names it's different. It depends on the case, but considering it unfeasible isn't correct.